# wordpress redirects every posts to the last post I published

Tags: wordpress

I have created a simple posts page in single.php. When I publish posts, the latest post displays for every previous posts links. :( Cannot understand what's the wrong with this.

All the pages redirects to the same page.

I am using wp 3.9.

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<div class = "right_sidebar" id = "main">
    <div class = "inner">
        <div class = "general_content clearboth">

            <!--Post Format Standart begin-->
            <div class = "main_content single ">

                <?php

                if (have_posts()) :
                    // Start the Loop.
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                        ?>

                        <?php $cats = get_the_category($id) ?>

                        <ul class = "breadcrumbs">
                            <li class = "home"><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class = "all"><a href = "page-style1.html">All Posts</a></li>
                            <li class = "cat_post"><a href = "page-style1.html"><?php echo $cats[0]->cat_name; ?></a></li>
                            <li class = "current"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                        </ul>

                        <h2 class = "page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                        <div id = "post_content" class = "post_content" role = "main">

                            <article class = "type-post hentry">
                                <div class = "post-info">
                                    <div class = "post_date">April 2, 2013</div>
                                    <a href = "post-standart.html" class = "post_format">News</a> <a href = "post-standart.html" class = "comments_count">0</a>
                                    <div class = "post_views">1045</div>
                                </div>
                                <!--<div class = "pic post_thumb"> <img src = "images/slider/image2.jpg" alt = "" > </div>-->
                                <div class = "post_content">
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "block-social">
                                    <div class = "soc_label">recommend to friends</div>
                                    <ul id = "post_social_share" class = "post_social_share">
                                        <li><a href = "http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=#" class = "facebook_link"><img src = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/facebook-icon-big.png" class = "facebook_icon" alt = "facebook" ></a></li>
                                        <li><a href = "https://twitter.com/share?text=#" class = "twitter_link"><img src = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/twitter-icon-big.png" class = "twitter_icon" alt = "twitter" ></a></li>
                                        <li><a href = "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?url=#" class = "gplus_link"><img src = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/gplus-icon-big.png" class = "gplus_icon" alt = "gplus" ></a></li>
                                        <li><a href = "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=#" class = "pinterest_link"><img src = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/pinterest-icon-big.png" class = "pinterest_icon" alt = "pinterest" ></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </article>

                            <?php
                        endwhile;
                    endif;



                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the page from scratch or there was a single.php and you just edited it? Because if you made it on your own, you should consult the wordpress docs, you might have missed something important like the class that loads the post ID.

This is how the Twenty Fourteen calls for the post in single.php.

```
    <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
             * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            // Previous/next post navigation.
            twentyfourteen_post_nav();

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }
        endwhile;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Dz. I'll check

Comment: I only have while (have_posts()) : the_post(); loop in single.php

Comment: get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); this returns nothing. I am using the_content()

Comment: What do you have inside the while function? Can you edit your question and paste the whole file?